# Not separable measure.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know the following definition of separable measure:

A measure $\mu$ is separable if there exists a countable family F of measurable sets of finite measure such that for any $\epsilon >0$ any measurable set A of finite measure, we can find a set B in F with $\mu(A \Delta B) < \epsilon.$

In a theorem related to seperability, a book writes like this:

Assume that $\mu$ is not separable. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ and an uncountable family of sets (say G) such that for all A,B in G $$\mu(A \Delta B) \geq \epsilon.$$
My question is, how does non separable measure imply the later statement. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this just contrapositive? Am I missing something?

Comment: In later statement there is uncountable, I don't understand how is it contrapositive

Answer (score 0):

- First some generalities.
  Suppose $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a measure space. Consider the collection of indicator functions of measurable sets $\mathcal{M}=\{\mathbb{1}_A:A\in\mathscr{F}\}$.  Notice that if $A,B\in\mathcal{M}$ have finite measures, then
  $$\mu(A\triangle B)=\|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B\|_1=\int_X|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B|\,d\mu$$
  It is then clear that on $\mathcal{L}_1(\mu)\cap\mathcal{M}$
  $$d(\mathbb{1}_A,\mathbb{1}_B):=\|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B\|_1=\mu(A\triangle B)$$
  defines a pseudo-metric (it fails to be a metric only in that that may be sets that differs by a set of measure $0$). By identifying sets $A$ and $B$ with $\mu(A\triangle B)=0$ we obtain a metric space $(S_M,d)$: the space of measurable sets of finite measure.
- It is  easy to se that the measure $\mu$ is separable (in the sense of the OP)  if and only if the metric space $(S_M,d)$ is separable.
- From this, we have that $\mu$ is not separable if and only if no countable set $\mathcal{F}\subset S_M$ is dense. That is, $\mu$ is not separable if and only if, for any countable set $\mathcal{F}\subset S_M$ there exists $A^*\in S_M$ and $\varepsilon>0$
  $$\|\mathbb{1}_{A^*}-\mathbb{1}_{B}\|_1=\mu(A^*,B)\geq\varepsilon$$
  for all $B\in\mathcal{F}$.